# How to add timer in button signals on gtk?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, glade

So I'm designing a virtual numpad with glade. It's working now but I wanted the buttons to print letters in a t9 fashion but I can't figure out how to time it... please help. my code so far is:

```
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
       #include <string.h>
       GtkWidget *g_entry1;

       int main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           GtkBuilder      *builder; 
           GtkWidget       *window;

           gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

           builder = gtk_builder_new();
           gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "labtest.glade", NULL);

           window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
           gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
           g_entry1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"entry1"));

       g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}


void on_btn1_clicked()
{
    gchar *num;
    char num_arr[20];
    num = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1));
strcpy(num_arr,num);
    strcat(num_arr,"1");
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1), num_arr);
}

void on_btn2_clicked()
{
gchar *num;

    char num_arr[20];
    num = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1));
strcpy(num_arr,num);
    strcat(num_arr,"2");
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1), num_arr);
}

void on_btn3_clicked()
{
gchar *num;

    char num_arr[20];
    num = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1));
strcpy(num_arr,num);
    strcat(num_arr,"3");
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1), num_arr);
}
void on_btn4_clicked()
{
gchar *num;
    char num_arr[20];
    num = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1));
strcpy(num_arr,num);
    strcat(num_arr,"4");
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1), num_arr);
}
```

and so on for the rest of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

(I wanted to put this as comment, but sadly I don't have *50 reputation*)

Please can you clarify your question.

> I wanted the buttons to print letters in a t9 fashion but I can't figure out how to time it.

what does it really mean? also, maybe you can give a link to **labtest.glade** file

---

**Edit:**

Ok, so you can use `struct timespec`, you may have something like this for your *button2*:

```
const gchar btn2_input[4] = { '2', 'A', 'B', 'C' };
struct timespec last_time_clicked;

#define MAX_DELAY 0.5f

void on_btn2_clicked() {
  struct timespec actual_time;
  float delay;
  const gchar *o_text;
  gchar *n_text;
  GString *s_text;
  static int i = 0;
  gssize text_len;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &actual_time);
  timespec_subtract(&last_time_clicked, &actual_time, &last_time_clicked);
  delay = timespec_to_float(&last_time_clicked);
  last_time_clicked = actual_time;

  o_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1));
  s_text = g_string_new(o_text);
  text_len = s_text->len;

  if(delay > MAX_DELAY)
    i = 0;
  else {
    text_len--;
    i = (i + 1) % 4;
  }

  s_text = g_string_overwrite_len(s_text, text_len, btn2_input + i, 1);

  n_text = g_string_free (s_text, FALSE);
  gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_entry1), n_text);
  g_free(n_text);
}
```

you may like to change **MAX_DELAY**, and there is the code for `timespec_subtract` and `timespec_to_float`:

```
void timespec_normalize(struct timespec *t) {
  int n;
  const int sn = 1000000000;

  n = t->tv_nsec / sn;
  t->tv_sec += n;
  t->tv_nsec -= n * sn;

  return;
}

int timespec_subtract(struct timespec *r, struct timespec *x,
              struct timespec *y) {

  timespec_normalize(x);
  timespec_normalize(y);

  if(x->tv_nsec < y->tv_nsec) {
    x->tv_sec--;
    x->tv_nsec += 1000000000;
  }

  r->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
  r->tv_nsec = x->tv_nsec - y->tv_nsec;

  return 0;
}

float timespec_to_float(struct timespec *t) {
  return (float)(t->tv_sec) + (float)(t->tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0f;
}
```

So all you need is to check if actual **delay** is greater than **MAX_DELAY**

Comment: text-on number in the sense if i press the button for 2 twice i should get A, if i press it thrice i should get 3 and so on